# Rails - Inheritance amongst multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to figure out the rails way to implement this. I have a table with types of vehicles

```
create_table :vehicles do |t|
    t.string make
    t.integer model_year
    t.string type #truck, motorcycle, sedan, etc
end
```

and instances of that car actually existing

```
create_table :vehicle_instances do |t|
    t.integer vehicle #links to above table
    t.integer owner
    t.integer bought_date
    t.integer mileage
    t.string type #truck, motorcycle, sedan, etc, but with different methods than above
end
```

1. I want the :type in the vehicles table to be moved to the vehicle_instances table. How would I go about doing this?
2. There may be cases where type is more specific in the vehicle_instances table (i.e. type:'motorcyle' in vehicles, but type:'dirt_motorcycle' or type:'road_motorcycle' in instances). Is there any way to catch both of those under the Motorcycle class when instantiating a Vehicle, but under the more specific class when instantiating a VehicleInstance?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Id have left it as an attribute of the parent, but if you must... In vehicleInstance do this:

   before_save :pull_type

   def pull_type
       self.type = self.vechile.type
     end

Also, change vehicle column to vehicle_id - it's expected syntax and will stop relationship conflicts.

1. Personally I'd add a column to instances of 'subtype': [dirt, race, nil]
   The options for subtype would be based on the parent type.